# Node S3Client Error - input.useDualstackEndpoint is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get a list of files within an S3 folder in a lambda written in typescript. I've added the following dependencies to my package.json.

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.41.0",
"@aws-sdk/node-http-handler": "^3.40.0",
```

I then use the S3 client like this:

```
const client = new S3Client({
    maxAttempts: 3,
    retryMode: 'STANDARD',
    region: getAwsRegion(),
    requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
      connectionTimeout: 3000, // Timeout requests after 3 seconds
      socketTimeout: 5000, // Close socket after 5 seconds
    }),
    credentials: args.credentials,
  });


  const listObjectsCommand = new ListObjectsCommand({
    Bucket: args.bucketName,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: pathToPartition,
  });
  const objects = await client.send(listObjectsCommand);
```

I've tried using ListObjectsV2Command as well, but it has the same error. The error is:

> TypeError: input.useDualstackEndpoint is not a function\n    at
> Object.getEndpointFromRegion
> (/var/task/node_modules/<my_module>/node_modules/@aws-sdk/config-resolver/dist-cjs/endpointsConfig/utils/getEndpointFromRegion.js:12:46)\n
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n
> at async Object.serializeAws_restXmlListObjectsCommand
> (/var/task/node_modules/<my_module>/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_restXml.js:2386:68)\n
> at async
> /var/task/node_modules/<my_module>/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/serializerMiddleware.js:5:21
> .

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened due to a mismatch is the aws-sdk version used in the package.json I had and the package.json of a dependency. Updating it to be the same version fixed this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working minimal version of your function.  Get this simple version working first and incrementally add complexity.

`AWS_REGION` is a lambda-provided env var.  I defined the `BUCKET` env var.  You can pass the bucket name with the event payload (or, to begin with, hard-code it to minimise sources of error).

```js
import { S3Client, ListObjectsCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const client = new S3Client({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
const bucket = process.env.BUCKET;

export async function handler(): Promise<void> {
  const cmd = new ListObjectsCommand({
    Bucket: bucket
  });

  const objects = await client.send(cmd);

  console.log(objects)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `getAwsRegion()` function gets it using the environment variable `AWS_REGION` as well, just with some logging. I've tried the simple command with only the bucket path earlier but it failed with the exact same error

Comment: That's disappointing.  I cannot replicate your error.  You need to do some debugging:  Try it with another bucket.  Try another SDK command (like [list buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/listbucketscommand.html) to see if the Client is working.  Try running `aws s3 listObjects` using the AWS CLI from your computer.  You get the picture.